# How to compile ocaml with android ndk

Tags: android, android-ndk, ocaml, cross-compiling

I am new to ocaml, and I am trying to use ocaml with android ndk but I can't figure out how the linking works. I already got c to work by itself and even haskell (using ghc-android)

Here is my c file that will call ocaml code. Right now I am just trying to get it to compile when I run ndk-build

jni.c

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <caml/callback.h>

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL JNI_OnLoad( JavaVM *vm, void *pvt ) {
  static char *argv[] = {"hello.so", 0 }, **argv_ = argv;
  caml_startup(&argv);
  return JNI_VERSION_1_2
}
```

hello.ml
    let ocaml_foo = 1.0

```
let () =
  Callback.register "ocaml_foo" ocaml_foo
```

Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := ocaml
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ocaml/hello.so

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := jni
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := jni.c
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := ocaml
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := /usr/lib/ocaml

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

The error is

```
fatal error: caml/callback.h: No such file or directory
```

I was trying to follow the instructions from [opam-android](https://github.com/whitequark/opam-android) but it doesn't have a full example. I don't see how to get the ocaml shared object to build with ndk

Do I have to compile both the ocaml code with the ndk code from ocamlopt? If so how?

Comment: You're using <> to include the mvalues.h, that tells the compiler to look only in the library path.  Is that file in the path?  Did you set up the path in your makefile?  Only the standard NDK libraries will be there if you didn't.  If its a local file use "" instead.

Comment: If the instructions from opam-android aren't clear enough, you should open an issue on their bugtracker.

Comment: @GabeSechan Thanks I figured that was part of it. I should have been clearer in my question. I don't know how to give an external library path in the Android.mk like in the example here http://www.mega-nerd.com/erikd/Blog/CodeHacking/Ocaml/calling_ocaml.html but for the makefile.

Comment: Add the path to your LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES variable in the makefile. That should be sufficient. It's what sets the -L parameter in your link

Comment: @GabeSechan I edited my question to reflect your advice, and I have verified that the file /usr/lib/ocaml/caml/callback.h exists. Unfortunately I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Try just LOCAL_C_INCLUDES+=your_path then.

Comment: Hi; if you found out something useful to how it can be done could you be so kind as to post it as an answer?